# Access the webserver by using javascript instead of php

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, webserver

I'm now using phonegap to develop a application. I have found a similar php code which can assess to a local server here, but unfortunately phonegap doesn't support php.

Can anyone help me to 'translate' the php code below into JQuery ajax or any other javascript code? Thanks!

```
require_once('nusoap.php');

  /* create client */
  $endpoint = "http://www.pascalbotte.be/rcx-ws/rcx";
  $ns = "http://phonedirlux.homeip.net/types";

  $client = new soapclient($endpoint);

  // queryRcx is the name of the method you want to consume
  // RcxQuery_1 is the name of parameter object you have to send
  // x and y are the names of the integers contained in the object
  $result = $client->call('queryRcx',array('RcxQuery_1' => array('x' => 12,'y' => 13)), $ns);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Resolve the 404 associated with http://www.pascalbotte.be/rcx-ws-rpc/rcx?WSDL
Step 2. [Get a JavaScript SOAP client](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient).
Step 3. `... ... ...`
Step 4. PROFIT!

Seriously though. All this really takes is a JavaScript based SOAP client. While they aren't a dime-a-dozen, they are pretty common. The one above is for jQuery, but it is easy enough to find [other](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx) [implementations](http://www.mathertel.de/AJAX/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx).

The fact that the `WSDL` definition causes a 404 may or may not be a problem as the actual `wsdl` definition is technically optional, but you really want to figure out what happened.

Comment: +1 for step 1 :)

BTW, is the crossdomain request policy applied to requests over phonegap?

Comment: Cross domain policies will continue to be cross. There isn't anything which can be done to change that.

Comment: Thanks, I havent used phonegap (yet), but I supposed it is only a tool to distrubute my html5 app, and any services I consume must be on my host (same as application itself), or have a proxy through it.

Comment: Sorry, i have made some modification above, changed it into SOAP instead of WSDL as I'm more familiar with SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this header to the PHP file or .htaccess to avoid problems with cross domain reqs:
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Replace the all(*) with your domain ;)

Good luck!